# How can I keep the roll of plastic wrap from falling out of the box?

Tags: kitchen

I find that pulling a sheet of plastic wrap out of the box can be incredibly tricky.

1. The plastic sticks to itself, so it takes a bit of force to pull it apart.
2. The force to pull the plastic off the roll is enough to pull the entire tube out of the box.

I can't seem to hold it in a way that keeps the roll inside the box, while allowing me to pull a sheet of the plastic out with enough force to pull it from the roll. If I'm holding onto the roll, then it can't roll to let plastic out.

Is there something else I can do?

Answer (score 8):

Most boxes of rolled kitchen items, like plastic wrap and aluminum foil, come with tabs on the box that you can press inwards.

If you press both tabs inward, they'll be inside the cardboard tube, holding it inside the box and working like an axle to allow it to roll, so that you can pull on the plastic wrap with a pretty reasonable amount of force.

[image]
[image]<sup>[source](http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2013/05/20/end_locks_aluminum_foil_and_saran_wrap_box_tabs_are_a_great_invention_photo.html)</sup>

If for some odd reason your box doesn't have these pre-cut tabs, you can easily take a knife or some scissors and cut them yourself.